# Little Dorrit Book the second chapter 2

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> A stiff commissariat officer of sixty, famous as a martinet, had then
> become enamoured of the gravity with which ***she drove the proprieties four-in-hand through the cathedral town society***, and had solicited to
> be taken beside her on the box of the cool coach of ceremony to which
> that team was harnessed.

What does the term "drove the proprieties four-in-hand"in preceding passage mean?

Answer (score 2):

> she drove the proprieties four-in-hand through the cathedral town society.

Quotes from OED:

> **7.b. the proprieties: the things that are considered proper; the details or rules of conventionally correct or proper conduct.**
>
> 1767   A. Murphy School for Guardians v. 73   *To break through all the proprieties of conduct.*

> **four-in-hand,** n. **1.a. A vehicle with four horses driven by one person.**
>
> 1793   European Mag. 23 46   *Swift thro' Hyde Park I drive my four-in-hand.*

To drive a coach and horses (also a coach and four/six/eight; four-in-hand) through something (figurative/metaphorical)

> **P3.b. to drive a coach and horses through and variants: to make something ineffective, esp. a law, policy, etc., typically by exploiting its loopholes.**
>
> 1691   W. King State Protestants of Ireland 63   *He was..often heard to say..that he would drive a Coach and Six Horses through the Act of Settlement.*
>
> 2020   Irish Daily Mail (Nexis) 6 Mar. 39   *Clever barristers can drive a coach-and-four through the thickets of the law.*

> she drove the proprieties four-in-hand through the cathedral town society

= she was easily able, with natural skill, to negotiate her way through the usual restrictions that the middle-class people in the town imposed on such people as her.

Comment: But Mrs General is a stickler for the proprieties, she doesn't 'drive a coach and horses' through them in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ***abstract allegory*** that Dickens uses in other parts of the novel as well. [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/children/academic-and-educational-journals/dickens-charles-1812-1870) explains:

> The Circumlocution Office is a dominant image in the novel—a point underscored by the way in which Dickens ***transposes the allegorical "proprieties" from the "cool coach of ceremony" to the hearse of the late Mr. General.*** *Abstract allegory* thus colonizes the real space that subsists outside it:
>
> > the whole team of ***proprieties were harnessed to his hearse***, and they all had feathers and black velvet housings with his coat of arms in the corner. (p. 447).

As for the OP's particular passage, the same site says:

> Since the governess seems to epitomize the Tory ethos of a Trollope novel, ***the conceit of a matron as coach driver*** (a conceit so improbable as to seem grotesque—imagine Mrs. Proudie driving a four-horse carriage!) ***suggests its essential inhumanity***. And here the underlying Gestalt of a woman in a chariot has to be that of Boadicea—an image likely to have been in people's minds in 1856.

Propriety is used in a literal sense here:

> conformity to what is socially acceptable in conduct or speech ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propriety))

In a usage note, M-W states that

> In an earlier era, when social manners were far more elaborate than they are today, ***propriety*** and ***impropriety*** were words in constant use. Today we're more likely to use them in other contexts. We may talk about the *propriety of government officials' dealings with private citizens*, *the propriety of the relationship between a lawyer and a judge*, or *the impropriety of speaking out of turn in a meeting* that follows Robert's rules of order.
>
> Relations between men and women still present questions of propriety, but today it's often in the workplace rather than in social settings. Wherever rules, principles, and standard procedures have been clearly stated, *propriety* can become an issue. Something *improper* usually isn't actually illegal, but it makes people uncomfortable by giving the impression that something isn't quite right.